# PHP + MySql, OR query with multiple error checks

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Currently I have to use 2 queries to check if database allready contains email or ip.

My code now:

```
        $link = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?");
        if($link->execute(array($login))){
            if($link->rowCount() > 0){
                $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email is already in use';
                $errflag = true;
            }
        }

        $link = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Ip=?");
        if($link->execute(array($ip))){
            if($link->rowCount() > 0){
                $errmsg_arr[] = 'There is allready account registered with this IP address';
                $errflag = true;
            }
        }
```

Is there way to check if email or IP is allready used if I use this query and how to do it?

```
$link = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? OR Ip=?");
```

EDIT: To be clear, I want to give 2 different errors, not one that tells user "Email or IP is allready in use"

```
    if($link->execute(array($login, $ip))){
        // WHAT HERE?
        // CHECK IF EMAIL IS ON USE
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email is already in use';

        //CHECK IF IP IS USED
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'There is allready account registered with this IP address';

        $errflag = true;
    }
```

So, is this possible with just 1 query?

I want to minimize use of queries.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try what you posted there, with the `OR` statement? Because that looks right to me.

Comment: Locking accounts to ips is not a good idea, thousands of people can use the same IP

Comment: Also its spelt `already` ;p

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (and since you use prepare() and execute, read [here](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.intro-execute.php)):

```
$link = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=? OR Ip=?");
if($link->execute(array($email, $ip))){
        if($link->rowCount() > 0){
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Email or IP is already in use';
            $errflag = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, Im looking way to give 2 different errors, not "Email or IP is allready in use". Can this be done with 1 query?

Comment: You can then compare results given by the query ($link->execute()) against the variables $email, $ip, and manually set error $messages. Simple as that.

Comment: Why did you link to `PEAR::DB`? OP is using PDO